# Qual a melhor forma de realizar uma operação de adição/subtração dependente?

Tags: php, estilo-de-codificação

É comum quando se esta no inicio se deparar com esta duvida.

Eu tenho de realizar uma operação que é dependente de um condição :

#### Exemplo 1

```
$operacao = 'somar';

$valor1 = 5;
$valor2 = 10;
$saldo = null;

if($operacao == 'somar'){
    $saldo = $valor1 + $valor2;
}else{
    $saldo = $valor1 - $valor2;
}

if($saldo != null){
    echo $saldo;
}
```

#### Exemplo 2

```
$operacao = 'somar';

$valor1 = 5;
$valor2 = 10;
$saldo = null;

$valor2 *= (($operacao == 'somar') ? 1 : -1);
$saldo = $valor1 + $valor2;

if($saldo != null){
    echo $saldo;
}
```

#### Questão

Qual a melhor forma de realizar esta tarefa, de tal forma que não ocupe muitas linhas, nem muita memoria?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É gosto mesmo.

Muitas pessoas gostam do primeiro porque ele parece mais claro.

Pra mim ambos são claros. Quem entende bem a programação consegue entender bem qualquer um deles.

Algumas pessoas vão dizer que o segundo exemplo é uma maneira *esperta* (*clever*) de fazer o mesmo. E isso pode ser bom ou ruim dependendo do contexto. Muitas vezes o termo é usado pejorativamente.

Eu provavelmente faria assim, afinal o segundo exemplo não é equivalente ao primeiro:

```
$operacao = 'somar';
$valor1 = 5;
$valor2 = 10;
$saldo = null;
$saldo = $valor1 + $valor2 * ($operacao == 'somar' ? 1 : -1);
if ($saldo != null) echo $saldo;
```

Ou poderia usar:

```
$saldo = $valor1 + ($operacao == 'somar' ? $valor2 : -$valor2);
```

Talvez eu tivesse uma função para isso, simplificadamente:

```
function InvertSignalConditional($value, $condition) {
    return $condition ? -$value, $value)
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Math/ConditionalArithmetic.php).

Note a inversão que fiz para ser correto, afinal você quer a inversão se a condição for verdadeira.

Em alguns casos pode optar-se mais por um que o outro por ser mais expressivo de qual é a intenção. Alguns dirão que o primeiro exemplo da pergunta é mais expressivo. Essa é uma forma imperativa de ver as coisas, para quem conhece programação funcional, que é muito mais expressiva que a imperativa, sabe que o segundo exemplo é preferido.

Comment: Mas e quanto a memoria?

Comment: Pouca memória, não?

Comment: Em relação a função, para não necessitar fazer `$var = Invert($var)`, eu alteraria para `Invert(&$var)`.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert tá aí alguém que sabe usar referências, rsrsrs. Eu não costumo visualizar usabilidade para elas, mas dessa vez percebo.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert O que tem a memória? Eu acho que não faria a função assim, tem que ter motivo melhor para gerar efeito colateral. Além do que, novamente, não poderia ser usada no caso do primeiro exemplo, elas não seriam equivalentes, e a função seria específica demais para outros casos. Se simplificar o nome, perde a expressividade que era o objetivo da função, se for fazer algo pouco expressivo, aí prefiro escrever o código.

Comment: Não, eu reduzi o nome apenas por exemplo, manteria o seu, apenas  quis comentar sobre o ponteiro. Quanto a memoria, o que gostaria de saber é qual usaria menos.

Comment: Não sei, teria que medir, talvez seja igual, mas se der diferença é tão pouco, mas tão pouca, mas tão pouca mesmo, que não faz diferença alguma, principalmente em PHP. Não estamos mais programando em SInclair com 2KB quando eu tinha que usar "1" onde podia usar número porque assim economizava 1 precioso byte :D E seria difícil comparar porque os exemplos não são equivalentes. Em tese o primeiro deve ocupar pouco mais de meia dúzia de bytes a menos por não precisar armazenar 2 constantes. Mas minha alternativa não causaria isto e provavelmente seria igual.

Comment: Não conheço profundamente a composição de memória do PHP, mas sei que ele desperdiça muita. Então nem vale a pena tentar ficar olhando pra isso. Se for relevante, vá fazer em C/C++/Assembly ou algo assim :)